# HttpInterceptor not working for all requests

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I am using the new version of angular and i am facing the issue of not sending authorization token within the request header for all some requests.
I checked everything and still the same problem since i upgraded to the new version 8.
When i send some requests, i couldn't find the authorization header even if i printed it in the console to check its presence.

This is the new version of Angular 8.

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest
} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable> {
    // Retrieve logged in user if connected
    const userToken = this.authService.getAuthenticatedUser();
    // Verify existing of the user
    if (userToken != null && userToken.bearerToken != null) {
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: userToken.bearerToken
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

### app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactUsComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    CartComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, CustomModule, LayoutModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: RequestInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I was expecting to have the authorization header.

Comment: provide your app module code

Comment: if some request don't have header with token is because there's NO token ..maybe post  your getAuthenticatedUser

Comment: Change != to !==. You should never use != unless you have a real reason to. For the requests where the header is not present place a breakpoint on your if statement and make sure that userToken and userToken.bearerToken both exist and are not undefined. I agree with federico you may want to post the getAuthenticatedUser code as well.

Comment: Sorry, thanks all for your responses. It was a server side issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` and your service and provide them in providers

```
<! app.module.ts -->
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequestInterceptor } from './your-interceptor-path'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: RequestInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

> You're cloning only `Authorization` header into the `HttpRequest`

Add following lines into your `RequestInterceptor` service next to `Authorization` header clone

```
if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
        }

req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json') });
```

Comment: I imported the service in the app module and still have the same problem. Some requests don't have the desired header.

Comment: This is clearly not the issue. This would cause compilation errors. His issue is some requests don't include the header

Comment: @Mickers I've updated my answer. I think it'll solve his issue. Can you upvote my answer.

Comment: May I know where you're storing the token? If you're storing in service instead of `local storage` or `session storage` it'll be deleted if the user refreshes the page. In your `interceptor` you're checking if token is not null and cloning the header. In the above scenario token will be null and that's why may be `Authorization` header is not adding.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. It was a server side issue.